# QT экспорт статического метода из динамической библиотеки

Tags: c++, qt, qtcreator

Собственно, вопрос описан в названии темы. 
Реально ли(и конечно интересует кроссплатформенный метод). Как я пытаюсь сделать:

```
#ifdef Q_OS_WIN
    #define DLLEXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
     #define DLLEXPORT
#endif

class Export
{
public:
    static DLLEXPORT void createLine() {...}
};
```

И пытаюсь вызвать:

```
using LibraryType = void(*)();

QLibrary lib("dynamic_library");
LibraryType creatorLine = reinterpret_cast<LibraryType>(lib.resolve("createLine"));
if(!creatorLine)
{
    // увы, метод не найден
}
```

Данный способ успешно работал в MSVS 17 - 19, с добавлением .def - файла. В QT никак не получается. Возможно, также требуется .def - файл, но как добавить в QT - не знаю. Дайте направление, как правильно экспортировать. Спасибо.

P.S.: по неизвестной причине метод QLibrary::isLoaded()const всегда возвращает false, даже если библиотека загрузилась успешно(в OS Win, другие пока не проверял). Сам новичок в QT, поэтому с этим не знаком.

P.S.S.: я исследовал dll с помощью dependency viewer и обнаружил, что у статического метода наименование искажено компилятором. Небольшая корректировка вопроса: как сохранить имя статического метода в "товарном виде", при этом используя только ООП(отдельные функции не приветствуются)?

Comment: А зачем вам тут `extern "C"`?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat действительно, это здесь лишнее.

Comment: После того, как вы его убрали, ничего не поменялось?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat нет, экспортируемое имя всё равно включает другие символы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При экспорте методов из классов, к ним применяется так называемая *декорация*. Для того что бы вам получить название метода, вам необходимо его узнать, это можно сделать либо во время отладки, воспользовавшись константой `__func__`, либо смотреть все экспортированные функции из класса. и искать нужное.

Для компилятора `VS`:

```
dumpbin /exports "someLibrary.dll"
```

Для `MinGW`, см [здесь](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/dlltool).

```
dlltool -d "someLibrary.dll" -e
```

---

Так же можно использовать пространства имен вместо классов, таким образом будет приемлимо использовать `__cdecl` для сохранения названий функций.

Comment: Дело в том, что я уже получил название метода. Но я хотел привести его в читабельный вид директивой extern "C" - но она не применима к static - членам класса. Вот в чём загвоздка. И я ищу решение без использования процедурного программирования.

Comment: Класс со статическими функцей, является процедурой, т.к. ни к какому объекту не привязан.

Comment: Бесспорно согласен, но в коде это выглядит более элегантно, чем набор функций? ИМХО конечно.

Comment: А что тогда вам мешает поместить вашу процедуру в неймспейс а не класс? Тогда будет применимо использовать `__cdecl`.

Comment: Я совсем забыл о пространствах имён..сделал, всё выглядит отлично, и , работоспособность, также, осталась. Спасибо огромное. Можете дополнить ответ - отмечу как решение :)

Answer (score 1):

Предполагаю, что не хватает вызова метода `load`

```
using LibraryType = void(*)();

QLibrary lib("dynamic_library");
if(!lib.load())
{
    //error, файл <dynamic_library> не найден или не хватает зависимостей
    return;
}

LibraryType creatorLine = reinterpret_cast<LibraryType>(lib.resolve("createLine"));
if(!creatorLine)
{
    // увы, метод не найден
}
```

Comment: Увы, не сработало. Метод всё также не найден.

Comment: @Range, у класса QLibrary есть метод ``errorString()`` из которого можно хоть предположительно понять в чем проблема.

Comment: Выполнил: не найдена указанная процедура (createLine)

Comment: @Range, Вы скорее всего не там вывод ошибки делаете, нужно ``errorString()`` выводить после вызова метода ``QLibrary::load``

Comment: Я сделал так, и смог проверять ошибки корректно. Спасибо большое, Ваш ответ тоже помог.